# WPF Popup MenuItem stays highlighted when using arrow keys

Tags: wpf, popup, menuitem

After opening a Popup menu programatically, if the user uses up and down arrow keys to move through the menu, menu items get highlighted and they never get unhighlighted.  What can I do so that after the user presses the down arrow, the previously highlighted menuitem becomes unhighlighted?

This happens with a very simple Popup menu:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Open Menu" 
            Click="OnPopupMenuButton_Click"
            Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />

    <Popup x:Name="MyPopupMenu" StaysOpen="False" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="White" Margin="0">
            <MenuItem x:Name="xAimee" Header="Aimee" Margin="0,2,0,0" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="xBarbara" Header="Barbara" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="xCarol" Header="Carol" />
            <Separator x:Name="xSeparator1" Margin="0,2,2,2"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="xDana" Header="Dana" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="xElizabeth" Header="Elizabeth" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Here is how the Popup gets opened:

```
private void OnPopupMenuButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;

    MyPopupMenu.PlacementTarget = button;
    MyPopupMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Mouse;
    MyPopupMenu.IsOpen = true;
    MyPopupMenu.StaysOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: Do you need exactly that way of popup menu declaring? If not, then simply use `ContextMenu`.

Comment: I tried using a ContextMenu, but it didn't work. I think I couldn't figure out how to make it open from a left-click. Also, I really need the placement flexibility that you get with a popup menu. I'll have to try a ContextMenu again and see what it was.

Answer (score 0):

I have been following up on archer's suggestion, but I had a few issues.  First, I did not want the menu to open on a right-click, partly because I just didn't want it to open on a right-click and partly because I actually need to use PlacementMode.Top, and the context menu kept opening in the standard context-menu place (to the side and down).

So in the end, I did end up using a Context Menu, but I did a couple of special things.  First, in the Window constructor, I set the button's ContextMenu to null, to prevent it from opening when right-clicked.  Then when the user left-clicks, I programmatically set the ContextMenu to the one that I created in the xaml file.  When the menu closes, I set the button's ContextMenu back to null.  I tried manipulating the ContextMenu visibility instead, but that did not seem to work as well as setting it to null and back to an object.

Here is the final xaml, not too different from the question exception that I am handling the Closed event for the ContextMenu.

```
<Button x:Name="xOpenContextMenuButton" Content = "Open Menu" 
    Click="OnContextMenuButton_Click"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
    Width="80" Margin="0,0,36,8" Height="23">

    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="xContextMenu" Closed="OnContextMenu_Closed">
            <MenuItem x:Name="xAimee" Header="Aimee" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="xBarbara" Header="Barbara" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="xCarol" Header="Carol" />
            <Separator x:Name="xSeparator1" Margin="0,2,2,2" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="xDana" Header="Dana" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="xElizabeth" Header="Elizabeth" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Here is the code-behind, which changed a lot:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    xOpenContextMenuButton.ContextMenu = null;
}

private void OnContextMenuButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    xOpenContextMenuButton.ContextMenu = xContextMenu;

    xContextMenu.PlacementTarget = xOpenContextMenuButton;
    xContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Top;

    xContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    xContextMenu.StaysOpen = false;
}

private void OnContextMenu_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    xOpenContextMenuButton.ContextMenu = null;
}
```

Once again, thanks to archer, because I didn't realize that using Popup was not the normal way to create a popup menu in WPF.  I think the root cause of the problem is, a Popup can contain anything -- a label, another button, etc.  Popup isn't necessarily expecting embedded MenuItems, so it isn't smart enough to understand that it should switch between my menu items when using the arrow keys.  But a ContextMenu expects to have MenuItems in it so it knows how to switch between them.

Comment: I also tried putting the ContextMenu inside a Popup.  This would be useful when I need the button with menu to appear inside each element in a Grid.  In this case, the menu items are inside a context menu.  I only need 1 Popup for the entire Grid.  This solved the problem with the arrow keys, but introduced a new problem: the background color for selected items now have a gray background, whether selected by mouse or arrow key, and since the selected item text is white, it is almost impossible to see them.  I haven't figured out the best way to set background color for this approach.